# Subscription system with days count down?

Tags: c#, php, mysql, days

I'm trying to make a subscription system where each user has a specific number of days on their account and everyday the number of days goes down by one until it reaches 0 days. How can I decrease the number of days of all accounts that have over 0 days, everyday and also output the date when the number of days will reach 0 in the format DD-MM-YYYY.

Thanks.

EDIT:

I found a way to convert days into date form in C# but how do I convert a date format into just the number of days?

Converting days into date format:

```
DateTime.Now.AddDays(subDayz).ToString("d-MMM-yyyy", new CultureInfo("en-GB"));
```

Maybe there is a way to do it in PHP, or do it in C# but prevent the user from changing the date to get more days?

Comment: Better add new column like `end_date`.

Comment: Use what is called a `WHERE` clause. The question's unclear though.

Comment: *"when the number of days will reach 0 in the format DD-MM-YYYY"* - You shouldn't be storing plain text dates here. MySQL has built-in methods just for this, and stores dates as `YYYY-MM-DD` when using a `DATE` column type.

Comment: What kind of format is `DD-MM-YYYY`? That's really irregular.

Comment: DD-MM-YYYY is a non-USA format especially UK, etc.  In Canada, we see both being used.  Can get really confusing when someone gives a date like 04-01-2018.

Comment: @BareNakedCoder [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) or bust! It's one of those formats that's extremely irritating as you never know when anything's going to expire. Is `04-01-2018` April first, in which case you're good, or is it January 4th, in which case that milk is nasty?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a countdown, when you create a new account set a database column to the date when the account expires (aka when the countdown ends) in DD-MM-YYYY format.  For example, if the account is created today ("31-03-2018") and expires in 15 days, set this field to "15-04-2018".

Now there's no need to update this (and all other active accounts) every day!  If in the future the current day's date is greater than this expiry date, then the account is expired (aka countdown ended).

BTW, to make it easier to compare dates, store in YYYY-MM-DD format and do simple string comparison.  Reformat if needed and as required for display purposes.

Comment: I would do that, but how can I add more days to that date? Because as you know, some months have 30 or 31 days, and February sometimes has 28 days, and I can't just add the number if days to the last sets of digits from the date string...